# How to check the number of empty text files in a folder in python?

Tags: python-2.7, text-files

I've a bunch of test files(around 2k) which i got after running a code and some of them are empty. So i want to print the number and name of those empty text  files. And all of those files have same extensions. I was trying this but didn't get the desired result.I don't know where i'm making the mistake.

```
for filename in os.listdir("/home/Desktop/2d_spectra"):
   if filename.endswith(".ares"):
      os.stat(filename).st_size == 0
      print filename
   else:
      None
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant to add `os.stat(filename).st_size == 0` to the `if`:

```
for filename in os.listdir("/home/Desktop/2d_spectra"):
   if filename.endswith(".ares") and os.stat(filename).st_size == 0:
      print filename
   else:
      None
```

Comment: yeah i just realized my mistake and your answer worked. Thanks for the help sir. @jh314

Comment: I think the community would benefit if that was asked as another question.